# PHP How to build a dynamic URL and then goto Location?

Tags: php, url, dynamic, get

Firstly, I don't quite understand the Location function in PHP, as it doesn't seem to do anything if I place it inside an if(isset) or an if($_GET) statement. 
Secondly and primarily, I'm interested in building a dynamic URL.

The idea is that, when a user clicks on an href, it Firstly adds the $Product variable to the $url, and then executes the href, displaying the new page.

I'm having a problem using href though, as I think it actually executes before the $_GET function, and therefore my $url is not loading the variables in to itself before executing.

I've partially got it working but it seems to add `Price=ASC` to the url every time I click on the second href.

```html
<?php
ob_start();
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'asd');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'asd');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'asd');
$link = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
$url = 'http://localhost/example/index.php?';
session_start();
$query1 = "SELECT Product, Price, FROM db1";  
$result1 = @mysqli_query( $link , $query1 ) or trigger_error("Data error."); 
$GETProduct = '';
$GETPrice = '';

if(!empty($_GET['Product'])){
 $GETProduct = '';
 $GETProduct = 'Product=' . $_GET['Product'] . '';
 }
if(empty($_GET['Product'])){
 $GETProduct = '';
 $GETProduct = 'Product=ALL';
 }
if(!empty($_GET['Price'])){
 $GETPrice = '';
 $GETPrice = 'Price=' . $_GET['Price'] . '';
 } 
if(empty($_GET['Price'])){
 $GETPrice = '';
 $GETPrice = 'Price=ASC';
 }
 
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<ul>
 <li><a href="<?php echo '' . $url . 'Product=TV' . $GETPrice . '';?>" 
  name="Product" id="Product" style="color:#000;"/>Product</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo '' . $url . '' . $GETProduct . 'Price=ASC';?>" 
  name="Price" id="Price" style="color:#000;"/>All Prices</a>
 </li>
</ul>
<?php 

echo $url;
echo '###########';
echo $GETProduct;
echo '###########';
echo $GETPrice;

?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating variable into a URL for PHP

`www.myurl.com/filename.php?object=myVar&object=myVar`

Take notice of the amperstand in the snippet above and add that to your code.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Are there any other examples of how to implement this? Google brought up only one example but it's only `$url = "www.example.com/" . $link;`

Comment: Please help. Been on this one for a week :s

Comment: The script above doesn't make a call to a database to retrieve anything.

Also, the output of the first link is `http://localhost/example/index.phpProduct=TV`

`http://localhost/example/index.php?Product=TV&Price=5.00` you would need to adjust your code:

`<a href="<?php echo '' . $url . '?Product=TV&' . $GETPrice . '';?>" 
  name="Product" id="Product" style="color:#000;"/>Product</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your second link you append 'Price=ASC' to the end of the url

```
<a href="<?php echo '' . $url . '' . $GETProduct . 'Price=ASC';?>" 
    name="Price" id="Price" style="color:#000;"/>All Prices</a>
```

What was your expected behavior?

Comment: Yes I did, only because $_GET wouldn't work without it. I essentially want to make it work without having 'Price=ASC' or even 'Product=TV'.